Importing SQL Table from Snowflake into Jupyter using Dask
I have an SQL Table in Snowflake,100K rows and 15 Columns. I want to import this table into my Jupyter notebook using Dask for further analysis. Primarily doing this a form of practice since I am new to Dask.
import snowflake.connector

connection_parameters = {
        'user': user,
        'password': password,
        'account': account,
        'warehouse': warehouse,
        'database': database,
        'schema': schema
}

-These are not my actual credentials (I changed so I can post here.
-Eventually, I will use environment variables, but going the simple route first.
query = """
    SELECT * FROM my_table
"""

from dask.distributed import Client
from dask import delayed
from dask.dataframe import from_delayed
 
client = Client()  # Start a Dask cluster

@delayed
def fetch_data(query):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    return cur.fetch_pandas_all()

Everything seems to work fine upto this point
import dask.dataframe as dd

try:
    with Client() as client:
        ddf = dd.from_delayed([delayed(fetch_data)(query) for _ in range(10)])
        result_df = ddf.compute()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

When I run this last code block, I get this error :
Error occurred: ('Could not serialize object of type HighLevelGraph'
I am stuck on this step, so any help would be appreciated. Again, I am new to Dask, so if ther is a simpler method I haven't considered, please recommend, my end goal is to bring in my data from Snowflake to Dask.

Did you have a look at https://github.com/coiled/dask-snowflake ?

To use your code, you should make your conn object within the delayed function.
